# [Suggestion]Tomcat7 automatic restart of application

Tags: java, tomcat7, continuous-deployment

I have my java application running on tomcat7 server.

/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT.war is my artefact.

If a replace ROOT.war(in the above path) with a new war(named ROOT.war) does tomcat7 automatically accepts the new war and restarts the service.

If yes,

1. How much time it takes to restart.
2. Is it 100% safe?

It will be even better if you can please give the documentation link explaining the same.

Also, please let me know if you need to some clarification on the above.

Comment: The `/WEB-INF/web.xml` web application configuration file is not checked on a reload; the previous `web.xml` configuration is used. If you have made changes to your `web.xml` file you must stop then start the web application.

Comment: Thanks @newuserua_ext. It was helpful.